# Что такое "попятный"?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

"Идти на попятный" - это значит отступать, чаще употребляется по отношению к спорам. Мол, человек пошел на уступки, отказался от своего мнения или требования.
Понятно, что слово "попятный" родственно слову "пятиться". И вот мне интересно, что такое этот самый "попятный"? Это ведь прилагательное, значит, подразумевается какой-то объект, существительное, к которому оно относится. Да и слово "пятиться" интересует (моя версия - когда человек идет задом, он шагает с пятки на носок - отсюда и слово). Но все-таки, что такое "попятный"?

Answer (score 2):

"Попятный" - это "попятный двор". Изначально - прилагательное ("попятный шаг", кстати, придумал Пушкин).
Откуда пошло выражение "попятный двор" - не нашёл. Но могу предположить, что это - пространство позади городских ворот и других узостей, используемых для обороны. В этом случае "на попятный двор" означает "отступить".

Answer (score 1):

Из словаря: ПОПЯТНЫЙ. Обратный, идущий вспять. П-ое движение, развитие. На попятный, на попятную (идти, пойти).Отказаться от данного согласия, прежнего решения.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

1) НА ПОПЯТНУЮ -  субстантивированное прилагательное с предметным значением.

2) Родственные слова: пятиться, пятка, вспять, опять. Старшее значение - пята (о.-с. petъ).

3) Пятиться - идти в обратную сторону.